# Android Recyclerview Issue

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, android-recyclerview

I am trying to get look and feel of some working app UI. Now i got stuck on one of its activity flow. Like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/velzyhgi4iz5614/20170108_221050.mp4?dl=0).
I am stuck on 2 things:

**Issue is** : How to get binding between marker and recyclerview like in video. I as well wanted to show marker according to item visible in recyclerview.

**Done**: I have tried recyclerview addonScrollListener but thats not working for me.

**Recyclerview :**

```
 final LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        this.bottomSheetAdapter1 = new com.development.haebix.adapters.BottomSheetAdapter(this, mEventInfos);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(bottomSheetAdapter1);
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

                setMarkerSelected(mEventInfos.get(newState).getMarker());
            }
        });
```

**Change marker color according to position code**

```
private void setMarkerSelected(Marker marker) {
        if (previousMarker != null) {
            previousMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(new IconGenerator(this)
                    .makeIcon("school")));}
        IconGenerator icon = new IconGenerator(this);
        icon.setStyle(IconGenerator.STYLE_ORANGE);
        marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon.makeIcon("school")));
        previousMarker = marker;

    }
```

> Please help me with some suggestions/advice so that i can achieve this.Thanks in advance

Comment: I think that is view pager not recyclerview.

Comment: @PushpendraChoudhary it is recyclerview

Comment: I am talking about your requirement based upon that link.

Comment: @PushpendraChoudhary yes i am as well talking about same. It is recyclerview

Comment: OK if you think so.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            int position = mLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            setMarkerSelected(mEventInfos.get(position).getMarker());
        }
    });
```

mLayoutManager is layoutmanager you use for recyclerview

Comment: No its not working . app is crashing on scroll with out of index. becoz Position coming -1

Comment: Are you doing it `onScrolled` or `onScrollStateChanged` ?

Comment: It's returning -1 if there are no visible items

Comment: Yes but its crashing on scrolling.

Comment: Try checking if position is not -1 before using it?